# Can't get OpenPyXl to delete rows

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using Python and OpenPyXL to merge two Excel reports.
When a report has a row of all zero values, that row should be deleted.

The command to delete rows seems simple enough, but it simply doesn't work. [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144059/how-to-delete-excel-rows-in-openpyxl) suggests delete rows doesn't play nice with `append`. I'm not using this function, but maybe there are other finicky bits?

I'm processing the Excel files opening and saving groups of actions. Here is a comment-for-code version of the block where I'm deleting these rows.

```
# Get WB
# Get WS
i = 0
del_rows = []
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    i += 1
    if row[0].value is None:
        # INVALID DATA ROW - BLANK ROW
    else:
        rowcellvals = []
        j = 0
        for cell in row:
            j += 1
            if cell.value == row[0].value:
                # INVALID COLUMN VAL - SKIP ACC NAME COL
                continue
            elif cell.value is None:
                # SKIP TITLE ROWS
                break
            else:
                # VALID DATA ROW
                if j % 2 == 0:
                    rowcellvals.append(cell.value)

        if not rowcellvals:
            continue
        else:
            if sum(rowcellvals) == 0:
                del_rows.append(i)

for r in del_rows:
       ws.delete_rows(r, 1)

# SAVE
```

Any ideas why delete rows is not deleting?

Comment: Don't use delete_rows in a loop, or if you do, reverse it.

Comment: reverse it? I'm not familiar with a Python idiom as such.

Comment: Read [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), view the example with **negative step**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are deleting rows from the top of the worksheet you are adjusting row indices as you go. This means that as soon as you have deleted a single row, the indices for all the other rows you want to delete are wrong. To avoid this you should always delete rows from the bottom of the worksheet.

```
for r in reversed(del_rows):
    ws.delete_rows(r)
```

---

Comment: Simply reversing the list of rows to delete won't suffice if rows to delete are interleaved with rows to leave in place.

Comment: Of course it will.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, realized that since commenting. I take back my comment and claim the opposite.