# openpyxl method for delete_rows not deleting last row

Tags: python, openpyxl, delete-row

I am trying to search for a Serial no in an excel file. Once I find the serial number I want to capture its row position and then I delete that row from my excel. My code is working fine except when the serial number happens to be in the last row, it does not delete it, the code executes but the row is not deleted. Can anyone help?

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws=wb[sheet]
r=0
for i in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
    if str(ws['C'+str(i)].value)==SN:
                    r=i
                    break

ws.delete_rows(r)
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get OpenPyXl to delete rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376617/cant-get-openpyxl-to-delete-rows)

Comment: @stovfl i have read this answer before. It is different than my issue. In your suggested post they cannot get openpyxl to delete the correct rows because every time they delete a row they are changing the position of the other rows. In my case, i am only deleting one row and it does work actually. It only does not seem to work when the row to delete happens to be the last row in the spreadsheet. The code is not even producing a error.

Comment: *"does not seem to work when the row to delete happens to be the last row"*: [Edit] your Question to [mcve] to show this behavior and how you verify *"does not seem to work"*