# Python 3.7.7, Openpyxl 3.0.3; How to: Properly use delete_rows() within a for iter_rows() loop?

Tags: excel, python-3.7, openpyxl, delete-row

This question involves the method in which the delete_rows() function of OpenPyxl modifies the row index number within an excel file.

**Goal**: With this snippet of code, I'd like to check a specific column for each row in a table, and if the column's cell value equals a particular value, or is empty, then I'd like to delete that entire row from the table.

**Problem**: When the delete_rows() function deletes a row, it seems to change the index of the remaining rows in a way that makes the rest of the rows not delete correctly (I introduce a row counter which adjusts based on whether or not a deletion occurs, but it doesn't seem to help).

Any ideas or advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**Link to sample.xlsx file**: https://filebin.net/c4gd9b4kd38burun

If the above link expires, here is a screenshot of what the sample.xlsx file looks like:
[image]

**Code snippet**:

```
#imports
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#load file
excel_file = "sample.xlsx"
workbook = load_workbook(filename=excel_file, data_only=True)
sheet = workbook.active

#deleting first row, and cleaning up headers
sheet.delete_rows(1)
sheet["D1"].value = "check 1" 
sheet["E1"].value = "check 2"

#remove all rows that start with years earlier than 2018 or are empty
row_number=2
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=2, values_only=True):
    for cell in row:
        str_cell = str(cell)

        if str_cell.startswith("2017"):
            sheet.delete_rows(idx=row_number)
            row_number = row_number - 1
        if str_cell.startswith("2016"):
            sheet.delete_rows(idx=row_number)
            row_number = row_number - 1
        if str_cell.startswith("2015"):
            sheet.delete_rows(idx=row_number)
            row_number = row_number - 1
        if str_cell == None:
            sheet.delete_rows(idx=row_number)
            row_number = row_number - 1

        row_number = row_number + 1         

#save as new file
workbook.save(filename="sample_test.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

After a little more research, I came across the following stackoverflow question:
[Can't get OpenPyXl to delete rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376617/cant-get-openpyxl-to-delete-rows)

User Charlie Clark points out that row deletions should be performed in reverse order to avoid the index issue.  I adjusted my code to implement this idea and I was able to get it to perform as desired.  I've attached my working code below in case it helps point in the right direction anyone else dealing with similar issues.

Code snippet:

```
#imports
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#load file
excel_file = "sample.xlsx"
workbook = load_workbook(filename=excel_file, data_only=True)
sheet = workbook.active

#deleting first row, and cleaning up headers
sheet.delete_rows(1)
sheet["D1"].value = "check 1" 
sheet["E1"].value = "check 2"

i=1
del_rows = []
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=2):
    i += 1
    rowcellvals = []
    for cell in row:
        str_cell = str(cell.value)
        if str_cell.startswith("2017"):
            del_rows.append(i)

        elif str_cell.startswith("2016"):
            del_rows.append(i)

        elif str_cell.startswith("2015"):
            del_rows.append(i)

        elif cell.value is None:
            del_rows.append(i)

for r in reversed(del_rows):
    sheet.delete_rows(r)

#save as new file
workbook.save(filename="sample_test.xlsx")
```